# Is it possible to check if returnType is a file in the OpenApi-Generator?

Tags: java, resttemplate, mustache, openapi-generator

I forked the openapi-generator plugin and wanted to change some things for my use.
I use the Java generator with the Resttemplate library.
I want to change the returnType if it is a file, so therefore
in the api.mustache I changed the code to `{{#returnType}}{{#isFile}}...`
But this doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This is achievable but in a slightly different way:

```
{{#isResponseFile}} ... {{/isResponseFile}}
```